# i got an error in vf page 'unknown property error"

Tags: apex, controller-extension

```
public class ListSelect {
    List<SelectOption>options  {set;get;}
    public string selected  {set;get;}
    public string result {set;get;}
    public listSelect(){
        options=new List<SelectOption>();
        SelectOption n=new SelectOption('-none-','none');
        SelectOption a=new SelectOption('tg','hyd');
        SelectOption b=new SelectOption('Kar','ban');
        options.add(n);
        options.add(a);
        options.add(b);    
    }
    public void getData()
    {
        result='you selectd'+selected;
    }

}

<apex:page controller="ListSelect">
    <apex:form>
        City:<apex:selectList size="1" value="{!selected}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
        <apex:commandButton value="submit" action="{!getData}" reRender="res"/>
        <apex:outputlabel value="{!result}" id="res"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Options are not public

Answer (score 1):

Change your `options` variable to look like this

```
public List<SelectOption>options  {set;get;}
```